# Replace file url with query string php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 1000 images in my website (running in codeingiter), which are named as

`My_image_1.png, My_image_2.png ........ My_image_1000.png`

and available in this url `http://example.com/files/My_image_1.png`

But i want the url is `http://example.com/images?cid=1.png` = `My_image_1.png`
How can i do this in php?

This is what i'm trying

```
if ( !function_exists('get_img_by_cid')) {
function get_img_by_cid() {
    if ( isset($_GET['cid']) ) {
        $cid = $_GET['cid'];
        return '/path_to_image/My_image_'.$cid.'.png';
    } else {
        return 'Please specify compound id';
    }
}
```

}

This function return the original path, but i need url like the example below.

In address bar or img tag wherever i use

Here is an example
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/image/imgsrv.fcgi?cid=2244

Any help or tutorial will be greatly appriciated :)

Comment: the URL you want is not a well-formed URL.

Comment: in php, you can build any string. so you have to be more specific in your question. show some code.

Comment: if the images are listed in the database then do a database lookup based upon `cid`. If the images are not in the db then you would need to decide some rules to process the GET request to serve `my_image_1.png` when `$_GET['cid']==1`

Comment: you can write htaccess rule instead writing the php code for it, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by following code.

Your URL = `http://example.com/images.php?cid=1.png`

write below code to `images.php` file

```
<img src="<?php echo "My_image_".$_GET['cid'];?>">
```

Above line will display image with named `My_image_1.png`

Hope this will helps you

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What if I put `$_GET['id'] = '../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd'`?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack,  actually the `"My_image_".` might save you.  but i wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write .htaccess rule :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^images$ /files/My_image_%1.png [L]
```

**Edit :**

## nginx configuration

```
location / {
  if ($query_string ~* "cid=([0-9]+)"){
    rewrite ^/images$ /files/My_image_%1.png break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The website using nginx

Comment: @MuhammadMorshed I've updated answer with nginx configurations, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code provided by [@Shishil Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579610/5373302), a friend and I wrote this:

```
<?php
$file = "My_image_".$_GET['cid'];
$size = getimagesize($file);
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
if ($size && $fp) {
    header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
} else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
readfile("{$file}");
?>
```

With this, `https://example.com/?cid=1.png` will display your image without any issues... as long as it's stored to index.php, otherwise your url is similar to `https://example.com/index.php?cid=1.png`, but with the proper php file name in the url.

**EDIT:**

On an additional note, `$file` should contain the folder path to your file, for example

`$file = "/path_to_image/My_image_".$_GET['cid'];`

Let me know if this was of use, your question was the same issue we had!